# cluster robust standard error in R after glm

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, stata, probit

my regression is the following

```
glm_test <- glm(formula=FormulaWritten,data=Regress_Sample,na.action=na.exclude,family=binomial(probit))
```

I want to compute the cluster robust standard error for this model. I wrote the following

```
 coeftest(glm_test, function(x) vcovHC(x, method="arellano",type="HC1",cluster="ID"))
```

Do you know if it corresponds to the Stata command

```
probit FormulaWritten, vce(cluster ID)
```

?

Comment: I think it is the same command, but beware that, in nonlinear models under heteroscedasticity, the estimates are inconsistent, even if you cluster the errors. http://davegiles.blogspot.com/2013/05/robust-standard-errors-for-nonlinear.html